# Object destructuring into class properties not working

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, es6-class, destructuring

The instance of this class is created like this:

```js
this.example = new Example(this.prop1, this.prop2);
```

Then, I'm trying to destructure these properties like this:

```js
export default class Example {
  constructor(params) {
    const { prop1, prop2 } = params;
    console.log('params', params);
    console.log('prop1', prop1);
    console.log('prop2', prop2);
  }
}
```

When I log these values, `params` returns data, but `prop1` and `prop2` are `undefined`, and they didn't properly destructure. Is it possible that the way I'm passing this data to the class won't work?

Comment: but you're not passing an object in `new Example`, you're passing two separate anonymous arguments, so `params` just maps to the first argument you passed. There is no object to destructure. If you want named property destructuring, use `new Example(this)`, because then you _are_ passing in an object with named properties that can be unpacked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible that the way I'm passing this data to the class won't work?

Yes. Your class constructor expects a single options object with two properties, `prop1` and `prop2`. Your call does however simply pass two argument values. You probably want to use

```
this.example = new Example({prop1: this.prop1, prop2: this.prop2});
```

or (if you don't care about other properties getting passed along) just

```
this.example = new Example(this);
```

Alternatively, keep your call and declare the constructor as `constructor(prop1, prop2)`, without any object destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing two different parameters to the function. What is being destructured there is actually the first parameter `this.prop1`. You have several options:

---

Pass an object:

```
this.example = new Example({ prop1: this.prop1, prop2: this.prop2 });
```

.

```
constructor(params) {
    const { prop1, prop2 } = params;
```

---

Pass the arguments separately:

```
this.example = new Example(this.prop1, this.prop2);
```

.

```
constructor(prop1, prop2) {
```

---

Pass an array:

```
this.example = new Example([this.prop1, this.prop2]);
```

.

```
constructor(params) {
    const [prop1, prop2] = params;
```

---

Use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

```
this.example = new Example(this.prop1, this.prop2);
```

.

```
constructor() {
    const [prop1, prop2] = arguments;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest passing an array.

```
this.example = new Example([this.prop1, this.prop2]);
```

Like @Bergi said one parameter. If you are looking for more then one param, then:

```
constructor(...params)
```

But this wont help you much on destructuring.